# Useful database queries

Tags: discussion

This post is for keeping interesting queries about cstheory.

---

Related meta questions:

- [Useful UserScripts?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/502/186)

Comment: fyi the avg quality questions/avg quality answers are the same query with different comments. the 1st seems to be the incorrect version. probably the `where PostTypeId = 1` clause needs to be adjd

Comment: ok tried again & didnt see issue. nevermind

Comment: these are useful, however also of interest would be general/macroscopic statistics showing total activity on the site over time, esp long term. any ideas, what is a reasonable metric of this sites overall participation/health/impact/popularity? [stackexchange normally uses question/answer volume, but this site is low in those areas possibly _by choice/intention/preference_ of participants.]

Comment: see also [number of questions/closed questions](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/the-number-of-questions-and-closed-questions?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

### [Find interesting unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions)

This query finds unanswered questions and sorts them based an estimated weight on how interesting they seem to be for the user running the query. The estimate uses: question score, asker's reputation, and how well you do on the tags for the question.

I guess this is similar to what they use for the [interesting questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

### [Monthly questions per area comparison](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/query/106229/cstheory-questions-per-month-top-areas-compared?num=10&YYYY=2010&MM=01#graph)

Shows the graph of the number of questions per month for top 10 areas

Answer (score 0):

### [Average quality of answers by users](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/query/106250/average-quality-of-answers-by-users?MinAnswers=10)

Average total votes of answers by users.

Answer (score 0):

### [Average quality of questions by users](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/query/106353/average-quality-of-questions-by-users?MinQuestions=10)

Average total votes of questions by users.

Answer (score 0):

### [Uncategorized cstheory questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/query/106341/uncategorized-cstheory-questions?num=100&YYYY=2011&MM=01)

Lists the uncategorized questions without cstheory area tags ordered by their last activity date.

Answer (score 0):

### [Closed questions per month](http://data.stackexchange.com/theoreticalcomputerscience/query/48851/closed-questions-per-month)

See also [Tsuyoshi's original post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/the-number-of-questions-and-closed-questions)